# Pandas/Python: split column based on a dictionary

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, split

I have a Pandas dataframe with a column containing comma separated values:

```
a,c,f
a,b,c,d,e
c,g,f,b
..
```

Each row has a different length, different order and values. It's the letter of the a to m.

I would like to transform it into 13 columns with 0 and 1:

```
a b c d e f g h i j k l m
1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

How would I do this efficiently in pandas / python 2.7?
I've thought of creating a column based on a test of presence or absence of a substring in the column.. but I can't believe there is not a more efficient way of doing it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) if column is `a`:

```
print df.a
0        a,c,f
1    a,b,c,d,e
2      c,g,f,b
Name: a, dtype: object

print df.a.str.get_dummies(sep=',')
   a  b  c  d  e  f  g
0  1  0  1  0  0  1  0
1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0
2  0  1  1  0  0  1  1
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I had get_dummies, but I had obtained 100+ columns.. I can't remember what I had done wrong! 'sep' doesn't appear as an argument in get_dummies: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html, how come?
--

Comment: I think you need [`str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) not [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html)

Comment: ooh, I see, thanks!
What is the difference between df.a.str.get_dummies(), which accepts the argument sep=',' and pd.get_dummies(), which does not accept the argument sep=','?

Comment: I think `str.get_dummies(sep=',')` is optimalized for `string` operation in `Series` (or column) and `pd.get_dummies()` is general function optimalized for works with all `df`.

Comment: Glad can help you! Good luck! And you can upvote my solution too - click to black triangle above `2` near `accept mark.` Thanks.